# How to make elasticsearch query with Python lists

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have dynamic lists returning from a microservice.

For example,

```
list1 = ["abc","def","efg"]
```

And I'm creating another microservice that does elasticsearch queries with Python.

Let's say I have an elasticsearch field called ***word*** and the type of the value of this field is ***string***.

I want to return items where this field value is equal to any element in the list.

Let's say we have an elasticsearch index named ***some_index*** that looks like this

> http://127.0.0.1:9200/some_index/_search?

```
[
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "bca"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "efg"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "xyz"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "mnt"
        }
    },
]
```

When we run this code template:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

list1 = ["abc","def","efg"]

es_query = {<the query i have to write>}

search = es.search(index="some_index", query=es_query)

print(search['hits']['hits'])
```

I want something like this to return:

```
[
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "word": "efg"
        }
    }
]
```

What is the query I have to write or do you have any advice for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `terms` query.

```json
GET /71196041/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "word.keyword": ["abc","def","efg"]
    }
  }
}
```

Which in you code should look like:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

list1 = ["abc","def","efg"]

es_query = {
    "terms": {
      "word.keyword": list1
    }
}

search = es.search(index="some_index", query=es_query)

print(search['hits']['hits'])
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I used it but it didn't work. I don't understand why it isn't working. It does not give an error, but returns zero results.

Comment: Ah damm my bad, use `word.keyword` ?

Comment: Oh it worked! Thanks mate, you are the best..

Comment: Awesome @evirbek, glad it did. Don't forget to validate the answer ;)